# JQuery $ signature missing string context

Tags: jquery, typescript

We are migrating some legacy javascript over to typescript.

We have JQuery selectors that are using a string as a context: `$("example", "someId")`, however when I migrate this over to typescript `JQuery.d.ts` does not have a definition which supports using a string as a selector. `(TS) Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | JQuery<HTMLElement> | Document'`.

According to the [JQuery spec](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) it actually does not accept a string even though the following example works.

> jQuery( selector [, context ] )
>
> selector Type: Selector 
> A string containing a selector expression
>
> context Type: Element or jQuery 
>  A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to
>   use as context

```js
console.log($("#test1 p").text());
console.log($("p", "#test2").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="test2"><p>test 2</p></div>
```

My question is, how do I support `$(html: string, context: string)` in my typescript?

I tried to define it in an interface but it made no impact:

```
interface $ {
    constructor(html: string, context?: string);
}
```

Comment: You could just fork the jQuery definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
I have found that it is an issue with `@types/jquery 3.3.31` which is resolved in version `@types/jquery 3.3.32` onwards. See: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/41979

Broken example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hh5tog?file=index.ts

Working example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7n7pm5?file=index.ts

---

I finally found the JQuery constructor I needed in the [`@types/jquery`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) library...

In [`misc.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/misc.d.ts) they had `$` declared as:

```
declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

And in [`JQueryStatic.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/JQueryStatic.d.ts) they have the constructor defined as:

```
<TElement extends Element = HTMLElement>(selector: JQuery.Selector, context?: Element | Document | JQuery): JQuery<TElement>;
```

---

So all that was left for me to do was overload this constructor in my own `JQueryStatic` interface and add string to the end of the type list for context.

```
// custom file
interface JQueryStatic {
     <TElement extends Element = HTMLElement>(selector: JQuery.Selector | string, context?: Element | Document | JQuery | string): JQuery<TElement>;
}
```

Comment: Not an override but an overload. Both signatures now exist. This is called declaration merging. Your solution is proper though.